# How to share same singleton service instance in library as well as the project using that library in angular 8

Tags: angular, events

I have created one component library which contains CommonService, DatastorageService services which are singleton in library that means I have given

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
```

also created some common Component like PriceComponents, it has button for calculate price.

I created build using ng build of the library and then copied the folder from dist to another angular projects node_modules folder to use those common component and services in other project.

After that imported library module to my project. also I have created one service which extends library service Commonservice

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class CCCommonService extends CommonService {
```

and Common service is like

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class CommonService {

  formElements: any = {};
  notes: any = {};
  calculatePriceEvent: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
```

In my case service is singleton in library not in whole project. but I need to get same instance of this library service in another project inside Angular.

but what happens when my app initializes first the CCCommonService constructor calling super constructor where CommonService  initializes , and when my pricecomponent from library uses commonservice methods again commonservice factory calls commonservice constructor, means two times commonservice constructor gets called.

But I want like Commonservice as well as CCCommonService  should have only one instance and should be initialized only once.

The impact of this is that price component is subscribing to the calculatePriceEvent of commonservice but event is not coming because of two times the commonservice constructor init.

```
export class CalculatePriceComponent implements OnInit {

  
  constructor(public commonService: CommonService) {
    this.commonService.calculatePriceEvent.subscribe(res => {
      //do some action
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is inherently flawed. there are 2 singletons, one `CommonService` and one `CCommonService`, that happens to extend the class `CommonService`. The injector tree doesn't care about inheritance and isn't aware of it. if you want the singleton `CCommonService` to send signals to the `CommonService` singleton, then you must inject it and connect events appropriately.

don't extend the `CommonService` inject it and wrap it.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CCCommonService {
    calculatePriceEvent = new Subject();

    constructor(private commonService: CommonService) {
      // mirror whatever you need
      this.calculatePriceEvent.subscribe(this.commonService.calculatePriceEvent);
    }

    // provide needed wrapper methods and extension methods
    wrappedMethod() {
      this.commonService.wrappedMethod();
    }

}
```

side note: don't use `EventEmitter` in services. use `Subject` from `rxjs`.